# Show the pager on the top and in the bottom of the page (generated by Views)

Tags: views, paging

I created a view and set a pager for it. 
I is shown in the bottom of the page. Is there any way to show it both in the bottom and in the top of the page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Copy `views-view.tpl.php` template file from `theme` subdirectory of `Views` module to your theme folder, edit it and duplicate fragment of code responsible for printing the pager:

```
  <?php if ($pager): ?>
    <?php print $pager; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

to where you want it.